# AppsFlyer iOS compile error: "AppsFlyerTracker.shared().delegate = self" fails

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, appsflyer

I'm integrating AppsFlyer into my iOS Swift 4 app w/ XCode 10.0.

CocoPods has installed AppsFlyer 4.8.9 SDK.

`import AppsFlyerLib` works.

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, I can access `AppsFlyerTracker.shared()` and set the dev key & app id.

However, the 3rd line of code required for integration fails to compile.
`AppsFlyerTracker.shared().delegate = self`

**Error message:**
`Cannot assign value of type 'AppDelegate' to type 'AppsFlyerTrackerDelegate?'`

**XCode's Suggestion:**
`Insert ' as! AppsFlyerTrackerDelegate'`

This suggestion does not work. The app crashes with the following error:

> AppsFlyer SDK version 4.8.9 started build (728)
>   Could not cast value of type 'MyApp.AppDelegate' (0x1057d0830) to >'AppsFlyerTrackerDelegate' (0x1056dcff8).
>   2018-10-27 18:17:49.448100-0700 Modacity[69104:7269920] Could not cast >value of type 'MyApp.AppDelegate' (0x1057d0830) to >'AppsFlyerTrackerDelegate' (0x1056dcff8).

Help? How do I set the delegate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This message occurs because you have not yet conformed the class to the `AppsFlyerTrackerDelegate` protocol.

add `AppsFlyerTrackerDelegate` to the class conforming to the protocol if this is your main AppDelegate do this:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, AppsFlyerTrackerDelegate { ... }
```

The documentation should tell you which methods to implement after that...

It may be a good idea to review [Protocols in the swift documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html) and learn about [Protocol orientated programing](https://www.raywenderlich.com/814-introducing-protocol-oriented-programming-in-swift-3).

From the documentation: 
[image: Image from AppsFlyer Docs]

Comment: This solved the problem thank you! Total oversight on my part. Cheers -

Comment: No problem, Sometimes it's the little things that get us most.